# How to capture output of Windows executable called from WSL

Tags: bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

For some reason while calling Windows executables (`powershell.exe`, `ping.exe`, and so on) directly from WSL works as expected, redirecting the output to a file or trying store the result in a variable fails.

What I have tried so far:

```sh
❯ powershell.exe 'Write-Host Fart!'
Fart!

❯ powershell.exe 'Write-Host Fart!' > file

❯ cat file

❯ output=$(powershell.exe 'Write-Host Fart!')

❯ echo $output
```

As you can see, by itself the command works. But combined with redirection or command substitution it does not work.

---

Edit: Restarting Windows resolved the issue. I think in the last session I somehow messed up WSL2 and its interoperability with Windows. Also noticed that other Windows executables like `clip.exe` stopped working. I was unable to pipe stuff to the Windows clipboard.

Now I restarted and things work again. Thought I was going nuts

--

Edit: Some infos about my system.

```
> [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      19042  0
```

Comment: I can start by offering the not-terribly-helpful (but informative, hopefully) "It's working for me."  I ran your commands, and `file` did smell of a `Fart!`.  Same with the `output=` version.  So some questions -- (1) What's your Windows release/build?  (2) What distribution are you using?  (3) If you install a different distribution, does it have the same problem? (4) Start with `wsl -e bash --noprofile --norc` - Does the problem still happen?   *-- (the reminder probably isn't necessary for you, but) Reminder to edit the new information into the question --* Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, wow I just tried it again after restarting my computer and now it works. I thing something was messed up with my WSL2. Also noticed that tools like clip.exe stopped working from WSL. Now everything works again. Pointing out that it works for you definitely helped, thanks

Comment: Cool - Good to hear it was that simple.  Just curious -- Were you attempting to do anything with Systemd, containers/namespaces, chroot, etc.?  Those are things (among others) that can interfere with the Interop socket.

Comment: Nope, nothing like that. Just working on my Ansible playbook. Now that I think about it `wslview` also stopped working and returned some kind of error I can't remember anymore. Maybe I will be able to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Windows resolved the issue. I think in the last session I somehow messed up WSL2 and its interoperability with Windows. Also noticed that other Windows executables like clip.exe stopped working. I was unable to pipe stuff to the Windows clipboard.

Now I restarted and things work again. Thought I was going nuts